# Query mongoose get last message each conversation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have model Chat:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
   userSend:        {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   userReceive:         {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   message :        {type: 'String', require: true},
   status:          {type: 'Boolean', default: true}, 
   time:            {type: 'Date', default: Date.now}
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Chat', schema);
```

Pls! help me query to get last message each other conversation. Same as facebook conversation.

it's sample data

```
{_id: '156478', msg: 'Hello lam', userSend: 'ZungX', userReceive:'Lam', timestamp: '2015-10-25T18:02:41.400Z'}
{_id: '586456', msg: 'hi My', userSend: 'Duc', userReceive:'My', timestamp: '2015-10-25T19:05:00.400Z'}
{_id: '254566', msg: 'Hello Duc', userSend: 'ZungX', userReceive:'Duc', timestamp: '2015-10-26T13:06:41.400Z'} 
{_id: '456899', msg: 'hi ZungX last', userSend: 'Duc', userReceive:'ZungX', timestamp: '2015-10-26T17:02:41.400Z'}
{_id: '987556', msg: 'Hello ZungX', userSend: 'Lam', userReceive:'ZungX', timestamp: '2015-10-26T20:01:41.400Z'}
{_id: '456878', msg: 'Chao Lam', userSend: 'ZungX', userReceive:'Lam', timestamp: '2015-10-26T21:54:21.400Z'}
```

Now, i want get list conversation of user 'ZungX'

I want this result:

```
[
    {   
        msg:        'hi ZungX last',
        withUser:   'Duc', //it's userSend
        timestamp:  '2015-10-26T17:02:41.400Z'
    },
    {
        msg:        'Chao Lam',
        withUser:   'Lam', //it's userReceive
        timestamp:  '2015-10-26T21:54:21.400Z'
    }
]
```

I have search same problem but i don't understand

Thank all :D

*'hi ZungX last' it is last message of 'ZungX' with 'Duc'. note: this message user 'ZungX' with role is **UserReceive***

*'Chao Lam' is last message of 'ZungX' with 'Lam'. note: this message user 'ZungX' with role is **UserSend***

Comment: You have duplicate _ids, also very hard to understand what the problem is. Try adding timestamps

Comment: Sr, i changed _id (it's demo sample data)  and add timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this exact problem - showing a list of conversation with a "from" and "to" field.
In your case you can do an aggregate similar to:

```
aggregate(
  [
    { $match: {$or: [{from: USERNAME}, {to: USERNAME}]}},
    { $project: {...FIELDS}},
    { $sort: { timestamp: -1} },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {$concat: [{$userSend}, {$userReceive}]},
        userSend : {$first: '$from'},
        userReceive: {$first: '$to'},
        msg: {$first: '$msg'},
        timestamp: {$first: '$timestamp'}
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

If like me however your "userSend" and "userReceive" fields were not plain strings (say ObjectIds), then it would be a good idea to add a "conversationId" field being saved as:

```
Chat.conversationId = [Receiver._id, Sender._id].sort().join('.')
```

Comment: thanks, this help

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired result as demonstrated by the following example:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "userReceive": "ZungX"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "msg": 1, "withUser": "$userSend", "timestamp": 1, "_id": 0
        }
    }
]

Chat.aggregate(pipeline)
    .exec(function(err, results){
        // handle err
        console.log(results);
    });

// Or use the aggregation pipeline builder for a more fluent call
Chat.aggregate()
    .match({ "userReceive": "ZungX" })
    .project({ "msg": 1, "withUser": "$userSend", "timestamp": 1, "_id": 0 })
    .exec(function(err, results){
        // handle err
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but i try it, haven't result. array is empty.

Comment: I run again, it run but, it is get current other user send for 'ZungX'. 
it not get result user 'ZungX send for other user.
I think use $group, but i don't know use it